# How did Indian diets change after arrival of Muslim kings?

Tags: india, food, ancient-india, mughals, indian

I would like to know how did the diets of people changed due to the new kingdoms that came in and took over the Indian Subcontinent. Was it earlier more vegetarian due to religious reasons and shifted to non vegetarian due to the new culture and as claimed by the Right Wing Politicians in India who say that the Mughals forcefully imposed their cultures or was the diet pretty much the same.

I've read about the eating habits on websites such as [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thebetterindia.com/157345/mughal-emperor-mughlai-food-history-india-news/amp/) but there is no authenticity.

Comment: What has your prior research found so far?

Comment: Lots of supposition, not a lot of evidence. The final sentence seems to veer away from historical inquiry into policy formulation and judgement.

Comment: I was speaking from a personal perspective and what i've observed and read historically. This in no means is a full article and as you rightly mention there are many vegetarians who are quite physically better.

Comment: @StackUpPhysics, please don't reply in comments. Update the question.  OP  should almost _never_ occur in comments.  I think the question would be stronger if you removed the second paragraph.  (don't comment, just either do the edit or flag the comment for deletion).

Comment: Point of biochemistry: Energy comes from glucose, which is primarily derived from carbohydrates.  Plant sources tend to be much higher in carbohydrates than meat.  Meat is mostly protein and fat.  Fat is either stored or converted to carbohydrates by the body in a process that's fairly lengthy.  Protein is used to build muscle, with any left over converted to energy in a process that is imperfect.  The upshot is that while meat is good for building muscle, what you want for the energy to march and fight is primarily grain.

Comment: Note that the Roman legions marched on grain, supplemented with whatever meat/vegetables could be scrounged.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I know all this my point is that this is what I think would've been the mindset according to me. Also Biochemistry wasn't too developed at that point for people to make such assertions

Comment: Did the Mughals believe a meat heavy diet was necessary?  (I.e. please add any prior research to the question.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap no I don't have any proofs for this claim I only think so on accounts I've heard of them having heavy diets but there were only anecdotes with no historical basis

Comment: Wikipedia gives a pretty basic [short answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Indian_cuisine).  Is there any sort of link behind the assertion that this was a forceful transition rather than a more typical cultural mixing?

Comment: @StevenBurnap I'm not saying it was a forceful transition. I just want to know how did it vary with the arrival of the Mughals and other Muslim Kings

Comment: I thought vegetarian diet was more of a Brahmin/Upper caste thing and that too limited only to Northern India? Southern India, IIRC, has always enjoyed non-vegan diet, including beef which is a no no in Northern India (And can get you lynched even in this day and age - Just to point out differences between North and South, both follow same religion but north is much more passionate about veganism and Cows than South is)

Comment: @NSNoob yeah I agree just a suggestion it would be better to use the word Vegetarian than vegan as they do consume milk

Comment: @NSNoob Your IIRC is wrong. South India does not "enjoy" beef, it's just an exaggeration by certain people to fabricate a "North-South" divide. Beef is eaten only in certain sections of the South-Western India, which is a sheer minority. Please don't bring in the lynching angle again, since it is another example of anti-India propaganda. Any manslaughter/murder in Indian villages are wrongly categorized as "cow based lynching", please validate the numbers from actual sources.

Comment: @varun since you're the one making the claim that I am wrong, the onus of proof lies on you. There's more than ample coverage of all the "Manslaughter/murder" incidents in all of global media and I am not entirely convinced by Indian nationalist conspiracy theory of foreigners stoking N-S divide. Please either substantiate your claims w/o repeating nationalist myths and denials or refrain from tagging me. Thanks.

Comment: @NSNoob This website facilitates forum for discussion, not for spoon-feeding. I flagged your comment on beef and N-S divide and asked you to research. Onus of proof? Did you give any proof when you said "get you lynched even in this day and age" or about beef? The AMPLE coverage of "fanatic" Hindus is intentional, do you see those global media discuss any other similar incident involving other religious sentiments? Think about it. Regarding lynching, it is unfortunate consequence of poor law enforcement, which we are fixing. You ought not to just dismiss my pointers as "nationalist myths".